# Quarkus/Hibernate - Hibernate Reactive Panache - Error Table 'quarkus.<DetailTable>' doesn't exist shown only for MySQL

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-hibernate-reactive

Quarkus/Hibernate - Hibernate Reactive Panache -  Error Table 'quarkus.' doesn't exist shown only for MySQL

I'm trying to create a Quarkus Hibernate Reactive Panache project pointing to mysql as database, using `quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create` to drop and recreate the database on Dev Mode.

As soon as I add either a @OneToMany or @ElementCollection field I start getting an error

`Error Table 'quarkus.<DetailTable>' doesn't exist`

during the `drop` stage of the `drop-and-create`.

Assuming there was something wrong with my project, I cloned the example code hibernate-reactive-panache-quickstart and tried adding it there. Only failed when I changed it to use mysql (from postgres) and stopped happening if I change the dependencies from reactive to classic.

A small change on the Fruit class:

```
package org.acme.hibernate.orm.panache;

import jakarta.persistence.Cacheable;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.ElementCollection;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheEntity;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Cacheable
public class Fruit extends PanacheEntity {

    @Column(length = 40, unique = true)
    public String name;

    //This field was added 
    @ElementCollection
    public List<String> colors;

    public Fruit() {
    }

    public Fruit(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

The log looks like this:

```
2024-03-27 19:44:15,964 INFO  [org.hib.rea.pro.imp.ReactiveIntegrator] (JPA Startup Thread) HR000001: Hibernate Reactive
Hibernate: 
    alter table Fruit_colors 
       drop 
       foreign key FKha93ebp4rpfvkmnj53gpbue88

2024-03-27 19:44:16,292 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2024-03-27 19:44:16,293 ERROR [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) {errorMessage=Table 'quarkus.Fruit_colors' doesn't exist, errorCode=1146, sqlState=42S02}
2024-03-27 19:44:16,293 WARN  [org.hib.rea.pro.ser.ReactiveGenerationTarget] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) HR000021: DDL command failed [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error executing SQL statement [{errorMessage=Table 'quarkus.Fruit_colors' doesn't exist, errorCode=1146, sqlState=42S02}] [
    alter table Fruit_colors 
       drop 
       foreign key FKha93ebp4rpfvkmnj53gpbue88]]

Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists Fruit
Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists Fruit_colors
Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists Fruit_SEQ
Hibernate: 
    alter table Fruit_colors 
       drop 
       foreign key FKha93ebp4rpfvkmnj53gpbue88

2024-03-27 19:44:16,357 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
2024-03-27 19:44:16,358 ERROR [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) {errorMessage=Table 'quarkus.Fruit_colors' doesn't exist, errorCode=1146, sqlState=42S02}
```

The database tables are properly created and all looks good, apart from the error show in the terminal.